# Boost Spirit Roman Numeral Parser Example

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Trying to learn boost spirit and the example given in the docs have me a little confused.

Referring to this code:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/roman.cpp

Particularly this segment of grammar:

```
        start = eps             [_val = 0] >>
            (
                +lit('M')       [_val += 1000]
                ||  hundreds    [_val += _1]
                ||  tens        [_val += _1]
                ||  ones        [_val += _1]
            )
```

Could someone explain to me why it is +lit('M') and not *lit('M'). Because after all can't there be zero or more M's versus one or more M's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `+lit('M')` and `*lit('M')` are correct.  But the former is more readable than the latter (semantically), in my opinion, as the former says **add** `1000` to `_val` if there is `one` match, and do it repeatedly. On the other hand, the latter is difficult to read, as one could read it as **add** `1000` to `_val`  even for zero-match which is wrong. `1000` is not added to `_val` for zero-times match, yet the parser `*lit('M')` seems to match for zero-match as well (seems kind of confusing).

So `+lit('M')` is preferable.

---

Alright. I read your comment. `CCLLIX` is not a valid roman number. What do you think its value is? `309`? If that is so, then what value would be for `CCCIX`? It's too 309, and its correct. Yours is wrong. Hence the parser stops when you use `*lit('M')`. Note also that the parser would also stop even if you use `+lit('M')` for this wrong input.

Comment: Using *lit('M') and CCLLIX. Then why does result return 250 and stop at LIX? Like u said, shouldn't it add 1000 to _val for zero matches and CCLLIX doesn't have an M. So shouldn't it return 1250 not 250?

Comment: @Integer: I added the explanation. `CCLLIX` is NOT a valid number.

Comment: Good catch. Sorry about that. But even if i use CCLIX both using * and + results in correct answer of 259. Why doesn't * result in 1259 like you say?

Comment: @Integer: I realized that `_val` is not updated for zero-match. So I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `a || b` operator in Spirit means `a` or `b`, but `b` after `a`, if `a` occurs. In the meaing of the operator, the case that there is no `M` is implicit (because the match for `M` may or may not be present). Also, in the case of `*lit('M')`, would you say that the first rule is matched if there is *NO* `M`? It would be valid anyway, and `_val` would be incremented by 1000.

Comment: But the _val doesn't get incremented when there is no M. I tried using input CCLIX and it returned correct value of 259 whether i use + or *

Comment: Well, that *may* be implementation-dependant. The semantics are clear in the sense that the rule *could* be matched (so it could execute the code), so it is better to use the `+`, because the 0 matches is implied by the `||` operator anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's (One or more Ms) OR hundreds OR tens OR ones. (Zero or more Ms) OR hundreds OR tens OR ones would match no Ms aka the empty string and meaninglessly add 1000.

Comment: This isn't true. I tried passing an empty string and it didn't add 1000 when using the Kleene star solution *lit('M')

Answer (score 0):

Matching the expression `A || B` in Qi means either matching just `A`, or just `B` or `A followed by B`. Therefore, in your case `+lit('M') || hundreds` means `+lit('M')`, or `hundreds` or `+lit('M')followed by hundreds`. For this reason the grammar allows to match any roman numbers not even starting with an `M`.